# JQuery offset() is returning only offset of only HTML document

Tags: jquery, html, dom, offset

I want to get the offset value of the div but i only get HTML document's offset i.e 0,0

here's the test code:-
HTML:-

```
<div id="result">Click an element.</div>
<div style="margin:auto; height:100px; width:134px; position:absolute; left: 193px; top: 53px;" id="name">JQuery</div>
```

SCRIPT:-

```
$("*",document.body).mouseover(function (e) {
  var offset = $(this).offset();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#result").text(this.tagName + " coords ( " + offset.left + ", " + offset.top + " )");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/isabab/1/edit)**</kbd>

```
$(function(){  // DOM IS NOW READY (document.ready shorthand)

    $("*").click(function (e) {
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        e.stopPropagation();
        $("#result").text(this.tagName + " coords ( " + offset.left + ", " + offset.top + " )");
    });

});
```

Read more here: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I don't know how i missed that.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing jQuery [.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event, include that and you should be good.